# not a function with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having an error when I try to refresh the data from a team.

Here is my project: I created a button to cancel the application when user send application to a team. But when I click into cancel button it will delete the application and then refresh the application data. but it's giving me `... not a function error`:

here is my following code where I get application that user sent to teams `TeamApplicationsReceived.js`:

```
  const [teamApplications, setTeamApplications] = useState([]);

  const fetchApplicationData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `/api/v1/invites/team/applications/${teamData.public_team_id}`
      );
      // Set state
      setTeamApplications(res.data);
      // Toggle loading state
      setLoadingState(false);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  // Load invites
  useEffect(() => {
    if (teamData.public_team_id) {
      // Fetch data
      fetchApplicationData();
    }
  }, [teamData]);

return (
    {teamApplications.map((theApplication) => (
      <Application
        key={`Received${theApplication.applicant_publicId}`}
        appData={theApplication}
        appType="received"
        fetchApplicationData={fetchApplicationData}
        teamData={teamData}
        fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
      />
    ))}
)
```

and here is file `Application.js`:

```
const Application = ({
  appData,
  appType,
  fetchApplicationData,
  teamData,
  fetchTeamData,
})

  const deleteApplication = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.delete(`api/v1/invites/app/delete/${appData.id}`);
      // Refresh application data
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log("success");
        fetchApplicationData();
        fetchTeamData();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

return (
 <div>
{
    modalStatus && (
    <CancelApplicationModal
      deleteApplication={deleteApplication}
    />
 )}
    </div>
)
```

Here is my `cancelApplication.js`:

```
const CancelApplicationModal = (props) => {
  const { deleteApplication } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box className="application-status-modal-container">
      <Button className={classes.buttonStyle} onClick={deleteApplication}>
        <CancelInvitation />{" "}
        <Typography className={classes.textStyle}>
          Cancel Application
        </Typography>
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Here is my error when I click cancel button:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How is `fetchApplicationData` defined inside `Application.js`? Looks like you're passing it in as a prop, are you destructuring it?

Comment: Is your axios.delete is successfull ? From what i see in the screenshot it looks like the cancel api request failed and you are in the catch block .

Comment: You have not provided the essential part of the code for this question: how fetchApplicationData is passed to Application.js.

Comment: @Shyam except the error shows you what went wrong and it was not the axios call.

Comment: @SajibKhan except he's not using class components, so probably not 'this'.

Comment: I passed it as props

Comment: @nathan, I created a Minimum Viable Example of your code and I can't replicate the issue. Please refer to this link to see the code, and tell us what you did different: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cgqx5n?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

at your child component `Application.js`, you pass in fetchApplicationData as props
You should use the function like `props.fetchApplicationData()`
or extract the function into variable like:

```js
const Application = ({fetchApplicationData, .....}) => {
    ......
    fetchApplicationData();  // use it
```